# Using Generics to Construct Instances of Child Classes

Tags: java, generics, java-8

While looking at some Java 8 code I saw some use of generics that I didn't quite understand, so I wrote my own code to emulate what was going on:

```
public class GenericsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestBuilder tb = TestBuilder.create(Test_Child::new);
        Product<Test_Child> p = tb.build();

        Test tc = p.Construct("Test");
    }

    static class TestBuilder<T extends Test> {

        private final Factory<T> f;

        public TestBuilder(Factory<T> f) {
            this.f = f;
        }

        public static <T extends Test> TestBuilder<T> create(Factory<T> f){
            return new TestBuilder<>(f);
        }

        public Product<T> build(){
            return new Product<>(f);
        }

    }

    static class Test {
        public Test(){
        }
    }

    static class Test_Child extends Test{
        public Test_Child(String s){
            System.out.println("Test_Child constructed with string '"+s+"'");
        }
    }

    interface Factory<T extends Test> {
        T create(String s);
    }


    static class Product<T extends Test>{
        private Factory<T> f;

        public Product(Factory<T> f) {
            this.f = f;
        }

        public T Construct(String s){
            return f.create(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Running this prints:

`Test_Child constructed with string 'Test'`

What I don't understand is:

1. Why don't you have to provide arguments to `Test_Child::new`
2. How calling
   `f.create()` in the `Product` instance refers to the
   constructor of the `Test_Child` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The method awaits `Factory<T>` as the input parameter:

   ```
   public static <T extends Test> TestBuilder<T> create(Factory<T> f)
   ```

   And `Factory` is an interface with only one method:

   ```
   interface Factory<T extends Test> {
       T create(String s);
   }
   ```

   That makes it effectively a functional interface, that can be implemented by simply passing a lambda: `Function<String, T>` (a function that creates an instance of type `T` from `String`). `Test_Child::new` is such a lambda, because it consumes `String` and produces `T`.
2. As stated `Factory` is a function, that takes a `String` and creates `T`. By calling the method `create`, we're invoking the function.

Answer (score 4):

> How you don't have to provide arguments to Test_Child::new

Since its a method reference for a representation of a lamda `s -> new Test_Child(s)` which is possible to create as the `Factory` interface ends up being a `FunctionalInterface` by its definition.

> How calling f.create() in the Product instance refers to the
>   constructor of the Test_Child class.

Since that's the instance type passed through the `TestBuilder`, to `Product` both having an attribute `Factory<Test_Child>`. It would be much clear when you rewrite the assignment as

```
TestBuilder<Test_Child> tb = TestBuilder.create(Test_Child::new)
```

To explain further as comments inlined with the code

```
TestBuilder tb = TestBuilder.create(Test_Child::new); TestBuilder
// TestBuilder<Test_Child> is build with a Factory<Test_Child> attribute

Product<Test_Child> p = tb.build();
// We have build a Product<Test_Child> which has a Factory<Test_Child> attribute from above

Test tc = p.Construct("Test");
// invokes the 'create' method of the Factory which calls 'new Test_Child(s)' to print the output
```